# Pull data as a string from a hyperlinked cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, links, google-sheets-cell-format

I have utility that I've been working on (modified from an existing sheet) for a Tabletop game I run for my group.

Currently, it generates random items from a list. The name of each of the items has a corresponding hyperlink to the items description from the same sheet.

[An editable copy of the generator may be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMVWCP_NxB3ZEQD9gb2SM5w97kBprbUlk0F9oTGythk/edit?usp=sharing).

My goal is to populate a new cell with with BOTH the item's name, and it's description.

So, if the generator returns an item name in cell "C4" with a hyperlink to its corresponding description cell, what formula should I use to populate this new cell (or cells) with both the name, and the descriptor?

**Here is an image of the generator, with the hyperlink to the description cell on a different page.**
[image: Generator Sheet]

**Clicking the hyperlink routes you to the corresponding "Description" cell.**
[[image: Description Cell][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jwck.png)

My ideal behavior, is for the formula to insert both the Name *and* the Descriptor into the new cell.

A visual example of the outcome I'm looking for can be found below.
[image: Cell with name and descriptor]

Any advice or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new sheet named `marikamitsos` and added **[`4 possible alternative solutions`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMVWCP_NxB3ZEQD9gb2SM5w97kBprbUlk0F9oTGythk/edit#gid=1706703035&range=I2)** on cells `I4:X4`.

I believe one of them will suit your needs.

**Solution 1**
The first one uses an added helper column (`M`) on your `Cyphers` sheet. Using this formula we manage to have a single cell with a link as we had in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138484/117311) :

```
=vlookup(B4,Cyphers!A:Z,13,false)
```

The newly added `Helper` column has the following needed formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(HYPERLINK( 
                "#gid=0&range="&L2:L632,ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(J2:J632)<>0,K2:K632&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&J2:J632,""))))
```

**Solution 2**
For the second one we just put together the twice used `VLOOKUP` function which again produces a single cell but no link this time.

```
=vlookup(B4,Cyphers!A:L,2,false)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&vlookup(B4,Cyphers!A:L,10,false)
```

**Solution 3**
On this third one we use the following formula which returns two separate fields one next to the other:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(vlookup(B4,Cyphers!A:L,{2;10},false)))
```

**Solution 4**
Finally the fourth solution is very similar to the third one. The only difference is that this time the two fields are one under the other

```
=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(vlookup(B4,Cyphers!A:L,{2,10},false)))
```

> ***Pro Tip***: 
>   *Instead of having 4 formulas in cells `C:F` you can use a single one (look at my examples on the sheet):*

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(B4,Cyphers!A:Z,{13,4,7,8},false))
```